# How to detect a drop not on the target but on the source in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a UserControl in my application which is stacked in a StackPanel.
I want to undock the UserControl from the StackPanel via Drag&Drop and drop it somewhere else in my application. This works fine as long as I can intercept the DragOver, DragEnter,... events but when I drag my UserControl outside my application/window I get a "not possible" cursor.

How do I know when I'm outside of my window and how do I know when the drop operation has been performed? I could find anything I can hook in.

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Mhmmm the only possible way i know is to use something like a dock panel. It gives some controls from different companys like telerik or so on. If you use a dock panel you can drag and drop your user control at any place on the display. But im not sure if this the thing accomplish your requierement.

Comment: Hi Kimbo. Visual Studio has such a behaviour. You can undock a tab and drop it somewhere on the desktop. I need to get behind the thing that is going on to intercept this. Thanks Martin